# does the payload_check query parser have support for simple query parser operators?

Tags: solr

I would like to use wildcards and fuzzy search with the payload_check query parser. Are the `*`, `?` and `~` operators supported?  Here are some examples of how I thought it would work:

```
{!payload_check f=text payloads='NOUN'}apple~1  
{!payload_check f=text payloads='NOUN'}appl?
```

The above queries match `apple~1|NOUN` and `appl?|NOUN` instead of using the `~` or `?` operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helpful people on the solr mailing list have informed me that the payload_check query parser does not support these features.